# In Django AuthenticationForm, how to check only email and password is_valid

Tags: django, authentication, email-validation

I tried to do this to remove username validation

```
def clean_username(self):
    return "valid_username"
```

But the `is_valid()` method is showing false. Even when i give the correct username and password

I also tried this

```
def clean_username(self):

    return self.cleaned_data.get('username')
```

**views.py**

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        

        form = LoginUser(request=request.POST, data=request.POST)

        

        if form.is_valid():

            print(True)

        

        

        print(form.cleaned_data['username'])

        print(form.cleaned_data['password'])

        

        print(form.is_valid())

    
    else: form = LoginUser()

    

    context ={

        'form': form,

    }

    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class LoginUser(AuthenticationForm):

    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': form_class, 'placeholder': 'username', }))

    password = forms.CharField(min_length=8, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': form_class, 'placeholder': 'password', }))

    

    def clean_username(self):

        return "valid_username"
```

I think I need to change the `is_valid` method

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, [substitue a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This modification removes the 'username' error from the form errors before calling the parent `is_valid` method. It effectively bypasses the validation for the username, allowing you to handle it in your custom way in the `clean_username` method.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms
            
class LoginUser(AuthenticationForm):
  username = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form_class', 'placeholder': 'username'}))
  password = forms.CharField(min_length=8, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form_class', 'placeholder': 'password'}))
            
  def clean_username(self):
    return "valid_username"
            
  def is_valid(self):
    # Skip the default validation for username
    self.errors.pop('username', None)
    return super().is_valid()
```